# CrushFTP on Azure VM giving "405 Method Not Allowed error" for POST method

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

We had CrushFTP installed on an Azure 2012 VM that recently died, so to speak. We wound up spinning up a new VM and reattaching the original data disk to the new VM.

After configuring IIS for the web portal part of CrushFTP, and cleaning up some script errors on the landing page, which is now on a 2016 VM, we get an HTTP 405 error when trying to log in to CrushFTP.

I checked to make sure the VM accepts POST requests - it does. The confusing thing is when I check the browser console, it's saying the server is NOT accepting POSTS, and this is happening both on our company network and from outside the network. I can see from our work network it's an issue with our proxy server, but from my mobile device outside of the network, I see the exact same rejected methods.

Any ideas? I don't have a whole lot of code to share since CrushFTP is a black box.

EDIT: I think the IIS setup was a red herring. I was going off some notes from a former co-worker who set this up, but I don't believe she set it up in IIS.

From what I'm reading, the CrushFTP HTTP server needs to be exposed as a public app through port forwarding in the VM. Whenever I run Crush locally on the VM, everything works fine. But since I set it up in IIS it hasn't worked.

Comment: have you confirmed the FTP ports you are using are open on the NSG for the new VM?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

Comment: I looked and there was no subnet associated with the NSG, which was already created and there was an inbound rule already set for port 80. After restarting the VM, same issue....

Comment: Wait, you mentioned and FTP rule and there is nothing set up for that....let me try that.

Comment: Still giving that 405 error

Comment: Check if [this](https://support.microsoft.com/fi-fi/help/216493/bug-you-may-receive-an-http-405-method-not-allowed-error-message-when) helps? a bug with IIS 4.0 or 5.0. This bug was corrected in Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0.

Comment: Thanks, Nancy. We're on IIS 11 so this wouldn't apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to add an "Allow" entry of POST in IIS.